# how to trigger the Name change to update in Infopath Form

Tags: infopath-rules

I need the Name field to be based on many values in the form.  I had rules on the Name field itself, and anytime one of the form field changes it set Name to " " and then back to "" in order to 'trigger' Name to use the rules on itself to update.  Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use a rule to set a field value on the submit button prior to submitting the data to Sharepoint. This builds a field that I then use as the fielname in the data connection.

Answer (score -1):

I used a bit of Jquery recently to be triggered on the submit e.g. "uploaddocuments()":

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

  function UploadDocuments() { 
   var a = $j(":input[title='a']").val(); 
   var b = $j(":input[title='b']").val();
   var c = $j(":input[title='c']").val();
   $j(":input[title='Name']").val(a + ' - ' + b + ' - ' + c );    
   return true;
  }

</script>
```